# Get all url from text by regex

Tags: regex

i need get all urls from the text file using regex. But not all url, url that start by some template. For example. I have text:

```
{"Field_Name1":"http://google.ru","FieldName2":
"["some text", "http://example.com/view/...&id..&.."]",
"FieldName3": "http://example.com/edit/&id..."}someText"
["some text", "http://example.com/view/...&id..&.."]",
"FieldName3": "http://example.com/view/&id..."}someText2{..}someText.({})
```

I need take all urls like `http://example.com/view/.....`
I try use this regex, but it doesn't work. Maybe i have some mistake in it.

```
 ^(http|https|ftp)\://example\.com\/view\/+[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?[^\.\,\)\(\s]$
```

I'm not need  pure url checker,  I need checker that can get url that start by some template

Comment: See [*JavaScript Regex to match a URL in a field of text*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188645/javascript-regex-to-match-a-url-in-a-field-of-text).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex for URL including query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343177/regex-for-url-including-query-string)

Comment: @stribizhev but what about "example.com/VIEW/...." i think with that part i have problem in my regex

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to parse the json?

Comment: @Yaron but if it's not valid json 'cause i have something like this "{json valid}Some text" so with "Some text" we have not valid json. and in each iteration Some text have different length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
((ftp|http[s]?):\/\/example.com\/view\/.*?)\"
```

The first part until "/view/" should be clear.  The rest ".*?)\"" means, show me everything before a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work! I gave it a go on regexr.com and it seemed to select just the url part, given that the text string doesn't actually have multiple periods in a row.

> (?!")h.+.+[a-z]*

EDIT: Made a better one, or at least I think I did. Basically the expression says: "look for a quotation mark, and if the next character is an *h* then include that in the match and also make that the starting point, and then include any characters after that leading to a single period, followed by any lower case letters. There could be a million of them. As long as there was a period before it, you're good, and it wont select beyond that unless theres another period after the string.

Comment: can you give all regex template to understand how you fixed it.

Comment: Updated. let me know if theres any confusion with my explanation.

Comment: Okay, but it's get all url http://example.com/edit/&..& and http://example.com/view/..&id.. but i need only http://example.com/view/..&id=..

Answer (score 0):

Universal:

```
/(ftp|http|https)\:\/\/([\d\w\W]*?)(?=\")/igm
```

Template:

```
/(ftp|http|https)\:\/\/example\.com\/view\/([\d\w\W]*?)(?=\")/igm
```

Comment: While this regex may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.